# best optimized sql query to select a single record name Jack from the list of 100 million record

Tags: sql, query-performance

best optimized performance specific sql query to select a single record name Jack from the list of 100 million record without using index

```
select name 
from table t1 
where name = 'JACK' -- normal query
```

Comment: https://use-the-index-luke.com/

Comment: There is no other way to write this query. If you need to improve performance, you need an index (see Mudassir's link). Performance questions also heavily depend on the database product being used. "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 1):

Make index on your table

```
CREATE INDEX idx01 ON YOUR_TABLE_NAME (name);
```

Comment: what if we don't have permission to set up an index

Comment: If there is no such index the best thing you can do for first is to ask someone who have permission to do it. If you use correct index, the query become a lot more faster.